# What is the easiest way to generate this UI?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

As subject asks, what is the easiest way to achieve the below input form?

[image]

Is it using UITableView? Or something else? I tinker around with code a little bit and I think I may be doing more work than I have to. I recall a presentation in which the presenter said that if I am doing too much hacking to get a feature, perhaps I am doing it wrong.

I searched the web for several frameworks and they are not sufficient. I tried ELCTextField. I try to use IBAForms which looks really good but the sample code is so confusing, I have no idea on how to use it. If you have any sample code, please share it and I would appreciate it. I also try RoundedUITableView and cannot get that to work.

Links to the frameworks:
1. ELCTextField: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/elctextfieldcell
2. IBAForms: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ibaforms
3. RoundedUITableView: https://github.com/beetlebugorg/RoundedUITableView

PS: When I try to combine RoundedUITableVIew with ELCTextField, everything breaks. It's heartbreaking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with two `UITextField`s set within a container `UIView` object. You will have to set the `borderColor`, `borderWidth` and `cornerRadius`. I've created some [`sample code`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/UserPass.zip) illustrating this.

Basically we will lay the two text fields adjacent vertically inside the container view. We will set the container view's `clipsToBounds` property to `YES`. We will assign borders to all the three objects and add a corner radius to the container view to get the effect as a grouped table view.

We will also add `rightView` and `leftView` properties of the two `UITextField` objects to get the padding effect.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a UITableView in grouped (UITableViewStyleGrouped) style, with a UITextField added to the table cell(s).  You can use the UITextField's `placeholder` property to get the gray default text value in the field.

Comment: @PengOne, This answer was not here when i started typing my answer. I'll delete mine

Comment: Thanks. I will work that out. Do you know of any good tutorial on grouped table view because the section and dimensions in IB are so annoying to work with. It's not really "what you see is what you get"

Comment: The best tutorial is provided by Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

Answer (score 0):

I achieved basically the same effect by having an image  as the background (although I guess you could place the content in tableView cells) and having a borderless textfield in each space that had default text in it.